# Return a confidence score in weka evaluation

Tags: java, weka, evaluation, confidence-interval

I am using weka's class evaluation in ordet to test my training results. The actual function that I am using for evaluation is eval.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction. I ve already trained my model and evaluate my test samples. My code is the following:

```
        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(dataset);
        //returned evaluated index
        double a = eval.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(c, dataset.instance(0));
        System.out.println(a + ", " + index2labels(a));
```

I want to calculate the confidence of the returned result. I browse the evaluation methods and I didnt find something satisfactory there.

Answer (score 0):

You could [trydistributionForInstance](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/AbstractClassifier.html) , as it says in the wiki it predicts the class memberships for a given instance.